# I want an anchor to move to the right when i hover over it with an ease in animation

Tags: css, css-animations

Basically I want the anchor to move to the right with a smooth animation when i hover over it. I have a '>' set before the anchor, which i don't want to move. I managed to do this on a website i made a while ago, but lost the files and don't remember how to do it. Would love to get some assistance.

```css
a::before {
    content: ">";
    color: black;
}

a:hover {
    right: -2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the right selector. `a:hover:before` selects the `:before` pseudo element when the  tag is hovered.

This assumes you have a lot more code that is missing here.

```
a:before {
    content: ">";
    color: black;
}

a:hover:before {
    right: -2px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that did nothing

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```css
a::before {
  content: ">";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

a:hover::before {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Linky</a>
```